# How to style a webpage so that an a href link appears to the right of a paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a link that was created with javascript appear to the right of a paragraph that was also created with javascript. The problem is that the link appears below the paragraph and text-align: center; and text-align: right; are not changing anything. Please help, here is the code:

The paragraph:

```
var p1 = document.createElement("P")
p1.className = "sideBar";
p1.id = "author"
p1.innerText = "By John Gruber";
document.body.appendChild(p1);
```

The link:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("Biden Will Make America Lead Again");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.href = "https://www.wsj.com/articles/biden-will-make-america-lead-again-11603127677";
a.className = "center";
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

The CSS:

```
.sideBar {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 0 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #eeeeee;
}

.center {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Gill Sans MT", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans Std", Verdana, "Bitstream Vera Sans", sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .15em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 1.05em;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    color: #ccc;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this, like using floats as mentioned by Mahmoud. I highly recommend learning flexbox for positioning. It will make your positioning so much easier. Also I see that you have not used universal selector to reset(Added sample).The solution is below

```
* {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 .sideBar {
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
     list-style: none;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-size: 1em;
     letter-spacing: 2px;
     line-height: 1em;
     color: #eeeeee;
 }
    
 .center {
     text-decoration: none;
     font-family: "Gill Sans MT", "Gill Sans", "Gill Sans Std", Verdana, "Bitstream Vera Sans", sans-serif;
     letter-spacing: .15em;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: normal;
     font-size: 1.05em;
     padding-top: 2px;
     padding-bottom: 0px;
     color: #ccc;
     text-align: right;
 }

 .container {
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
 }
```

index.js

```
var div1 = document.createElement("div");
div1.className = "container"
document.body.appendChild(div1);


var p1 = document.createElement("P")
p1.className = "sideBar";
p1.id = "author"
p1.innerText = "By John Gruber";
div1.appendChild(p1);

var a = document.createElement('a');
var linkText = document.createTextNode("Biden Will Make America Lead Again");
a.appendChild(linkText);
a.href = "https://www.wsj.com/articles/biden-will-make-america-lead-again-11603127677";
a.className = "center";
div1.appendChild(a)
```

Comment: I don't know what flexbox or universal selector is as I am fairly new to web development, but your code worked so thank you very much!

Comment: Yeah I had a feeling. I really recommend learning it. You will love how easy it makes your life as a developer. Universal selector is the *{} code added. it makes margin and padding of all elements 0. Do a little research on border-box. Nice concept

Answer (score 1):

P (paragraph) tag is a block level element and it will take the full width of the container and always starts on a new line. you can give display:inline to the .sideBar class.

```
.sideBar {
text-decoration: none;
display: inline;
list-style: none;
letter-spacing: 2px;
text-transform: uppercase;
margin: 0 0 1em 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 1em;
letter-spacing: 2px;
line-height: 1em;
color: #eeeeee;
```

}

Comment: I tried that but it just made everything a mess by not having new lines on anything. I tried applying it to an id on just the paragraph but then the paragraph centered itself and won't move to the left

Answer (score 0):

It's because you make `.sidebar` a block-level element. (Also the `<p>` is block-level element by default)

Block-level elements by default pushe content to the "next line" and take up all horizontal space.

The easiest way to fix your problem without major changes in JS is to make `.sidebar` inline-block element. (`display: inline-block`)

`inline-block` is better in your case than `inline`, because if you set either of this your `.sidebar` and `.center` would appear one after another, but only with `inline-block` you could specify a `margin` that takes effect

Comment: I tried this but it just everything to be a mess by not having any spacing between lines. I then tried applying it to just an id on the paragraph which fixed it other than the paragraph is centered now and I can not get it to move to the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

add `float: right;` inside **.center** and add `float: left;` inside **.sideBar**